# Can Juju interact with already installed Openstack service?

Tags: juju, openstack, zfs, solaris

*(I didn't find any answer to my question after having looked in a lot of posts)*

I'm currently deploying an Openstack private cloud.
- I would like to run Solaris 11.2 (or OpenIndiana/similar) on my storage server and use ZFS for my block storage needs (= Cinder), maybe even for object storage ( Swift on ZFS)
- I have an other server with lots of RAM/CPU & lots of NICs inside. I would like to use it as my Openstack controller node & network node.
- I have 4 nodes in one 2U chassis that I want to use as Compute Nodes

My question is : Can I use MAAS & Juju to deploy on everything but the storage server, and then "connect" my charms to it even if the storage server is not "listed" in Juju (as it can't run Juju being Solaris based) ??

Regards,
Y

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be more of a OpenStack charm question. With that said I do not think the charms (specifically cinder/swift) support connecting to an existing storage cluster.

I recommend filing bugs for the services you're interested in incorporating existing infrastructure with a Juju deployment.

Cinder: https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/cinder

Swift: https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/swift-proxy

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this kind of thing with Juju in the general case by writing a "proxy charm".

The job of a charm is to provide an implementation of a particular service in terms of defined relations and open ports. So you can always write a charm that implements the service by actually proxying to another service (in this case your manually deployed Solaris-based storage node).

The charm would set relation data to point consumers (at the other end of its relations) to the real service instead. Usually the `private-address` relation setting is configured by default, but your charm can always override it by setting it directly to point it to the real service in this way.

I don't know whether such a thing would best be incorporated into the existing Swift and Cinder charms, or you would be better writing your own replacement charms. So filing bugs as @gangstaluv suggests for the former case is probably still a good idea.

But the point of my answer is that yes, you can always do this by the nature of Juju's architecture.